# Postgresql update using join using postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two table named MAIN_WAYS and SUB_WAYS.

```
MAIN_WAYS (id, producer, geoemtry, length, size, ...)
SUB_WAYS  (id, producer, geometry, ...)
```

So I want update SUB_WAYS producer column same as MAIN_WAYS producer column where touches geometries. 
I can join these two tables sql select.

```
select 
    sw.id sw_id, 
    sw.producer sh_producer, 
    mw.id mw_id, mw.producer mw_producer 
from 
    sub_ways sw,
    main_ways mw    
where 
    st_touches(mw.geometry, sw.geoemtry);
```

And

```
sw_id    sh_producer  mw_id   mw_producer
1        null         1       x
2        null         2       x
3        null         3       y
4        null         5       z
```

One main way may touches multiple sub ways. In this stuation, all subways that touched one subway will be same producer.

```
update  
    sub_ways
set
    producer = mw.producer
from
    sub_ways sw
inner join
    main_ways mw on st_touches(mw.geometries, sw.geoemtry)
where
    st_touches(mw.geometries, sw.geoemtry) and  
    sw.producer is null;
```

Buth this query set all sub way producer as same values.

How can update this?

Comment: Is there a main way id key in sub way table ?

Comment: No there is no relation for id columns. Only geometry touch relation. And I can get touched records using `st_touches(mw.geometries, sw.geoemtry)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not joined your update table with your result (from clause) so it updated to values from the last record of your set from clause.

```
update  
    sub_ways sw
set
    producer = mw.producer
from
    main_ways mw 
where
    st_touches(mw.geometries, sw.geoemtry) and  
    sw.producer is null;
```